# IE Windows Theme, CSS and Current Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am using a custom jQuery select checkbox list, which unlike the default select lets you select more than one object using a checkbox. This supports ThemeRoller, but since the rest of the controls on my page are native html (selects, buttons, etc) I want the custom select to also look native.

I created a style for this based on Win XP IE 7, but it of course looks funny if the user is not using XP or has a different theme e.g. Server 2003. The main issue is the border colour and style.

I have tried getting the border properties from a native control on the page using:

```
var borderStyle = select.currentStyle.borderStyle; //returns none
var borderWidth = select.currentStyle.borderWidth; //returns 1
var borderColor = select.currentStyle.borderColor; //returns #fffff
```

But these values are incorrect (see code comments), I was expecting it to return a solid light blue border. I have also tried select.style.border and its variations with no luck.

Is there a way that I can correctly detect the native/default border style of a select in Internet Explorer and then apply this same style to my custom control?

Comment: you might try to just check for the xp theme itself, as some scripts out there do, eg http://notetodogself.blogspot.com/2010/03/jquery-detect-windows-xp-theme.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is CSS2 `System Colors`.

In CSS2, a number of pre-set color names are defined which map to the default colors of the operating system.

So you could, for example define your buttons in CSS like this:

```
.mybutton {background: ButtonFace;}
```

...and they'd pick up the colour that the OS uses for buttons.

The down-side is that these System Colors are now deprecated in CSS3, which means that you probably shouldn't be using them, and browser support isn't guaranteed (and may be removed in future versions).

The reason they're deprecated is because the list of colours used by the operating system differs between virtually every OS, even different versions of the same OS.

For example, the spec includes a definition for `WindowFrame`, but of course in recent versions of Windows, the window frame has a transparent gradient effect which no longer makes sense in context of a single colour as per the spec. Another example is that the spec defines colours for 3D highlights and shadows, but of course 3D effects are more subtle now than they were when the spec was defined.

If you want to give it a try anyway, you can find the W3C's specification for System Colors here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#system-colors

Hope that helps.